# Android Out Of Memory error with with images

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

For some reason I can not load any image that has more than 200 pixels in either width or height without getting a OOM error. To fix this I lowered the amount of pixels on my images but now they all look blurry. Does anyone know the best way to load higher quality images without getting this error. Also I have tried manually recycling my bitmaps but when doing so it seems to just give me the out of memory error no matter what size the images are.

Comment: are you only loading **one** of these images (200px) and getting an OOM error?  or, are you loading many?  are you running in a severely memory constrained environment?  (are you using a simulator, or a real phone, and if so, which model ... and how much free memory)

Answer (score 3):

The inSampleSize of the BitmapFactory.Options class can solve your issue, Try to see the officiel android docs [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and you will get it work.